# Android | Exoplayer | Recording - How to record streamed Video from Exo-player In Android?

Tags: exoplayer

I want to record streamed video locally from Exoplayer. 
ight now am able to play HTTP stream into my Android Device using Exoplayer. I need to record that streamed video into my phones local storage.

Thanks
Anshuman

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately ExoPlayer does not support recording of stream. Here is link on [developers answer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1167)

**UPDATE**

I find my own solution for this problem. If you still need it, you can see it here:
[Recording of RTMP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488926/recording-of-rtmp-stream/58639279#58639279)